# How to add a class to li element which has a ul child element in pure Javascript not jQuery

Tags: javascript, html-lists

How can i add a class to an `<li>` element which has a child `<ul>` element. I found there are so many examples in jQuery but not in Javascript. I would like to do it in Pure Javascript for Performance Optimization. The code is as follows: Thanks in Advance!

```html
<nav id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li> <!-- >>> I want to add a class to this <li> element as it has a <ul> child element -->
       <a href="#">Services</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="">Graphic Designing</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Web Designing</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</nav>
```

Comment: Grab all `<li>` elements and check if one of their `.children`s is an `<ul>` element, or grab all `<ul>` elements and check if their `.parentElement` is an `<li>` or grab all `<ul>` elements that are a direct child of an `<li>` element, or ...

Answer (score 4):

I think you need something like this

```js
// -------- vanilla js

document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((el) => {

    if(el.querySelector('ul')) el.classList.add('theClassNameYouNeed');

});

// -------- jQuery (just to see the difference) :)

$('li').each(function() {

    const el = $(this);
    if(el.find('ul').length) el.addClass('theClassNameYouNeed');

});
```

Useful resources to move from jQuery to pure Javascript (Vanilla):

- http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/
- https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/move-from-jquery-to-vanilla-javascript/
- https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/7307312

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((el) => {

if(el.querySelector('ul')) el.classList.add('theClassNameYouNeed');

});
```

```css
.theClassNameYouNeed {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Graphic Designing</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Web Designing</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: "without using jquery"

Comment: This would also add the class to the outer `<li>` in `<li><div><ul><li>foo</li></ul></div></li>`

Comment: @WaisKamal yes, without using jQuery, you have both version :)

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry for that. Better remove the jQuery version cuz it's not what the OP asks for :)

Comment: Thanks Francesco Orsi, to shown me the both version to understand logic.

Comment: @RenJitsm You're welcome. Please remember to mark one of the answers by clicking the check mark at the top left of your favorite answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible way of adding the class to the `li` element which has `ul` as child

```js
const liElem = document.querySelectorAll("li")


liElem.forEach(elem => {
  if(elem.querySelector("ul")) {
    elem.classList.add("new-class");
  }
})
```

```css
.new-class {
  color: red;
  background: #ececec
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Graphic Designing</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Web Designing</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: This would also add the class to the outer `<li>` in `<li><div><ul><li>foo</li></ul></div></li>`

Comment: Thanks Nithish, for your example

Answer (score 2):

You can do this **two** ways below using only `JavaScript` off-course.

Here is simple `direct` solution to add class to the `li` which has `ul` in it. This selects the first `li > ul` in the DOM and apply class to it using classList and [add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) method.

**Live Demo:**

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let getLiUL = document.querySelector('li > ul')
  getLiUL.parentElement.classList.add('foo')
});
```

```css
.foo {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li>I want to add a class to this element as it has a child element
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Graphic Designing</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Web Designing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</nav>
```

Here is solution which uses `querySelectorAll` method and `forEach` loop. This loops through all the `li` in the `DOM` and apply class to the only `li` which has `ul` as a child.

**Live Demo:**

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let getLiUL = document.querySelectorAll('li')
  getLiUL.forEach(function(e) {
    e.querySelector('ul') ? e.classList.add('foo') : " "
  })
});
```

```css
.foo {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li>I want to add a class to this element as it has a child element
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Graphic Designing</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Web Designing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</nav>
```

**References:**

[ClassList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: This would also add the class to the outer `<li>` in `<li><div><ul><li>foo</li></ul></div></li>`

Comment: @Andreas With current structure => **No** it will not - whats the point here coming up with your own scenarios ? Solution is provided to HTML structure given.

Comment: That's known as a "hint" for OP for a possible problem if the structure is slightly different or if it changes in the future.

Comment: Thanks AlwaysHelping, for your example

Comment: Andreas hint is good to know if the menu is going to a complex structure. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

**Demo snippet**

```js
const liElems = document.querySelectorAll('li');
liElems.forEach((elem) => {
    const childrenElems = elem.querySelectorAll('ul')

    if(childrenElems.length > 0){
      elem.setAttribute("class", "democlass")
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Graphic Designing</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Web Designing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```